# Apply PBR Textures on 3D model using Image Based Lighting

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

In ARKit 2.0, I am trying to use PBR base material. Using 3D model in `.obj` file format.

**Problem**: I am not able see the dark product. I am not sure, if it's related to set proper lighting in SceneKit. Please help me how to set PBR base lighting in `ARKit`/`SceneKit`.

Try below code:

```
//Set lighting
let light = SCNLight()
light.type = .ambient
node.light = light

// if light estimation is enabled, update the intensity 
// of the model's lights and the environment map
if let lightEstimate = self.session.currentFrame?.lightEstimate {
    self.enableEnvironmentMapWithIntensity(lightEstimate.ambientIntensity / 1000.0)
} else {
    self.enableEnvironmentMapWithIntensity(6)
}

// Call environment Map
func enableEnvironmentMapWithIntensity(_ intensity: CGFloat) {

    if sceneView.scene.lightingEnvironment.contents == nil {
        if let environmentMap = UIImage(named: "Models.scnassets/sharedImages/environment_blur.exr") {
            sceneView.scene.lightingEnvironment.contents = environmentMap
        }
    }
    sceneView.scene.lightingEnvironment.intensity = intensity
}
```

Required Result : http://prntscr.com/luwlax

[image]

For reference, attaching PBR Materials:

[image]

Diffuse : https://prnt.sc/luwc40

Roughness : https://prnt.sc/luwcl7

Normal : https://prnt.sc/luwcuw

Metalness : https://prnt.sc/luwdaz

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ***separated geometry*** (a screen separately from frame), it's easy to assign texture onto these parts.

If you have a ***combined geometry*** (all parts as one piece) the only way to texture such a model is to assign [pre-made UV-mapped texture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDXEvQdCEKk).